# PHP разложить текст на слова

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите, как разложить текст на слова, желательно в массив, мне вообще нужно будет перебирать их через циклы, например:
слово1 слово2 слово3, слово4.
Можно ли и если можно то как перебирать их в циклах, а вообще можно ли их запаковать в массив, например такой:
"0" => "слово1"
"1" => "слово2"
"2" => "слово3"
"3" => "слово4"

Comment: Можно, делается просто, учебник по пхп, прочитать от корки до корки>профит, мы умеем разбивать строки на слова(хоть в массив хоть в никуда). если совсем лень читать учебник то explode, split - можно погуглить.

Comment: автор, ты просишь делать за тебя ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНЫЕ вещи. почитай учебник Котерова по ПХП прежде чем задавать такие простейшие вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'слово1 слово2 слово3 слово4';
$text_explode = explode(' ', $text);

print_r($text_explode);
```

**Результат:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => слово1
    [1] => слово2
    [2] => слово3
    [3] => слово4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-word-count.php)

```
$str = 'Hello, world! Вот так';
$words = str_word_count($str, 2);
var_dump($words);

// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(5) "Hello"
//   [1]=>
//   string(5) "world"
// }
```

Работает только с латинскими символвами, хотя можно указать доп.символы, которые будут считаться словами и получится что-то вроде этого:

```
$words = str_word_count($str, 2, 'Вотак');

// array(4) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(5) "Hello"
//   [1]=>
//   string(5) "world"
//   [2]=>
//   string(6) "Вот"
//   [3]=>
//   string(6) "так"
// }
```

Но в таком случае уже лучше [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), которого, в свою очередь, тоже может быть недостаточно и придется делать [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)